# How to distinguish ELF files running on Android and on traditional Linux?

Tags: android, linux, format, elf

I got an ELF (Executable and Linkable Format) file, how to know if it's supposed to be used on the traditional Linux platform, or the Android platform?

On Android, most are .so files.
I tried to use some strings embedded in the file, like JNI functions or "Ljava" libraries to distinguish them, but the result seems not so good.

Any more accurate way to distinguish them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do this by using `readelf --dynamic` to read the `DT_NEEDED` entries and distinguish them using the `SONAME` for libc.  On a glibc system, you'll likely have `libc.so.6`, although there are other libcs out there, like musl.  The libc that Android uses is Bionic, so it will likely be different.

This doesn't work for static binaries, such as most Go binaries, but most people don't distribute static binaries for Android.

For executables, you may also wish to read the `PT_INTERP` header, which will tell you which dynamic linker is in use.  That should differ between systems.

Comment: Did not see Bionic in most Android ELF files...  Can we use these kinds of strings to distinguish?
Ljava/,  libandroid.so,  or JNI functions.

Comment: Bionic's libc isn't called "Bionic".  But the SONAME will probably not be `libc.so.6`.  There may be other libraries in the `DT_NEEDED` entries that do indicate a difference.  You'll just have to look at some binaries from the two systems and develop some general rules.

Comment: Any way to distinguish for .so files?

Comment: SO files usually have a dependency on some other shared library, such as libc.  The same techniques can be applied as I mentioned in the original answer.